# Newbie WPF Animation: How to begin the Animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have Created a custom animation class followed this guidelines [WPF Tutorial - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18379/WPF-Tutorial-Part-2-Writing-a-custom-animation-cla):

```
public class EarthAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    private Earth _earth = new Earth(250);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof (int), typeof (EarthAnimation),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int From
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(FromProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FromProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof (int), typeof (EarthAnimation), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int To
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(ToProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new EarthAnimation();
    }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof (int); }
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue,
    AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        Vector fromVal = ((Earth) GetValue(EarthAnimation.FromProperty)).Coords;
        Vector toVal = ((Earth) GetValue(EarthAnimation.ToProperty)).Coords;


        return new DenseVector(new[]
        {
            _earth.DistanceToStar*Math.Cos(_earth.WE*animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value),
            _earth.BE*Math.Sin(_earth.WE*animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value)
        });
    }
}
```

My Xaml Look this(*simplified*):

```
<Grid Name="MyCanvasGrid"
    Width="600"
    Height="400"
    Background="Transparent"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasDrawingArea"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ClipToBounds="False"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        RenderTransform="1 0 0 -1 0 0">
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I want to begin my animation(*in Code*) when the `PlayBt` is pressed.

```
private void PlayBt_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DrawEarth();    
    var dbAnim = new EarthAnimation();

    dbAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    dbAnim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

    // Set the start value and end value. 
    dbAnim.From = 1;
    dbAnim.To = 3660;
}
```

How can I begin the animation in code?

Comment: Thx for the reply. I cant find any `Begin()` function but there is a method called `dbAnim.BeginAnimation()`. it has two parameter that I can't really figure it out.

Comment: you need to add storyboard in animation..without storyborad how animation cam begin.in your code no storyboard.and thats why you are not find out storyboard.begin().check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pars It's wrong what Heena Patil is telling you here. You don't need a Storyboard to start an animation of a dependency property in WPF. That's why there is a BeginAnimation method in class UIElement. Having said that I have the feeling that you need to read one or two article about animations in WPF before you start coding. Start reading perhaps here: [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx). This may also be helpful: [Property Animation Techniques Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970492.aspx), esp. the part about per-frame animations.

Answer (score -3):

For Start an Animation, you need to launch the Animation with the function "Begin()";

```
dbAnim.Begin();
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. I cant find any Begin() function but there is a method called dbAnim.BeginAnimation(). it has two parameter that I cant really figure it out.

Comment: [Example For BeginAnimation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms598906(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: -1 because the method name is `BeginAnimation`, not `Begin`, and it is defined in the `UIElement` class, not in `AnimationTimeline`.